# Get data from API call to 3rd party system and display it in Promethues

Tags: prometheus

I am new to Prometheus and am trying to write a custom exporter using python libraries. For this I am using `prometheus_client`.

My end goal is to monitor my vault node. I have a number of APIs that I can use to gather metrics for my vault node. At the end of this I want my promethues dahsboard to say something like :

```
vault_total_conection <some-number>
vault_total_secrets <some-number>
```

and so on.

The base python code that I got from https://github.com/prometheus/client_python is :

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Summary
import random
import time

# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')

# Decorate function with metric.
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request(t):
    """A dummy function that takes some time."""
    time.sleep(t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)
    # Generate some requests.
    while True:
        process_request(random.random())
```

Now I have the API setup towards vault all figured out. I have a function that contacts vault and returns a float number.

```
def extract_metric_from_vault():
    // some code
    return float_number
```

So this function is defined in the code above. What I am having trouble to understand is how to integrate this with promethue client. I want to use Gauge since I know the value will be high or low.

So I try to do somethin like :

```
TEST_VALUE   = Gauge('vault_total_conection', 'Description of gauge')
TEST_VALUE.extract_metric_from_vault()
```

But this clearly doesnt work.

I get the ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.yaml", line 8, in <module>
    TEST_VALUE.extract_metric_from_vault()
AttributeError: 'Gauge' object has no attribute 'extract_metric_from_vault'
```

So can someone just guide me as to what I need to connect the dots here. I want to pull some value from an API call using a function and display it in prometheus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You need to call your function in `main()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# Start up the server to expose the metrics.
start_http_server(8000)
# Generate some requests.
while True:
    extract_metric_from_vault()
```

And then, you need to the value of gauge

```
TEST_VALUE.set(<extracted value>)
```